# Where to insert an #include when multiple files need it C++

Tags: c++, include, header-files, compiler-optimization, pragma

Let's say I have 4 source files main, aux1, aux2 and aux3, all of whom work with strings and therefore need to `#include <string>`.

The main one will include the 3 aux, since it will use it's functions, but none of the aux needs to include main nor any other aux.

Where should I include string and how could something like `#pragma once` help me with this situation?

Comment: The general guidance I give is *include what you use*.  If a file (header or source file) has a dependency on `std::string`, then that file should `#include <string>`, regardless if one of its other header files also does the same thing.  On the flipside, files should **not** include headers that they do **not** depend upon.  Reliance upon indirect dependencies does not scale.  In your own header files, you can put non-standard `#pragma once` at the very top of the header file; or alternatively or in addition to, you could use header guards (which is supported by standard C++).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Headers should include what they use. Deviating from this leads to pain on the long run. Hence:

```
// aux1.h
#include <string>

// aux2.h
#include <string>

// aux3.h
#include <string>

// main.cpp
#include "aux1.h"
#include "aux2.h"
#include "aux3.h"
```

You could in principle include `<string>` in `main` before you include the other headers, then the code will compile even if the other headers do not include `<string>`. However, this is very fragile, because then correctness of your code depends on order of includes. The `auxX.h` headers should be correct independent of what other headers have already been included or not.

> [...] how could something like #pragma once help me with this situation?

You should use header guards for your own headers, though `<string>` already has header guards and including it multiple times is a not something you need to worry about.